# How to insert a new column in a dataframe and pass on values to it based on some conditions using a for loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need to create another column in my existing data frame. To this new column, I need to pass on some values using a for loop and the values are of string type. I am unable to obtain the desired output.

I have first created a series and I tried passing on some string values to this series through a for loop. After this, the series is passed in pandas insert function to append series in the Data Frame with values passed.

Here I want to create a column named Type_new which has the categories as Low Potential and High potential.

data2 is an existing data frame and I am creating this new column called Type_new in the same data frame

The code used is as shown below along with the error message.

Kindly share your views to help me sort out the issue.

```
Type_new = pd.Series([])

for i in range(len(data2.Status)):
if data2[‘Status’][i]==‘Junk Lead’:
Type_new[i]=‘Low Potential’
elif data2[‘Status’][i]==‘Not Responding’:
Type_new[i]=‘Low Potential’
elif data2[‘Status’][i]==‘Just Enquiry’:
Type_new[i]=‘Low Potential’
elif data2[‘Status’][i]==‘In Progress Negative’:
Type_new[i]=‘Low Potential’
elif data2[‘Status’][i]==‘LOST’:
Type_new[i]=‘Low Potential’
elif data2[‘Status’][i]==‘CONVERTED’:
Type_new[i]=‘High Potential’
elif data2[‘Status’][i]==‘Potential’:
Type_new[i]=‘High Potential’
elif data2[‘Status’][i]==‘Long Term’:
Type_new[i]=‘High Potential’
elif data2[‘Status’][i]==‘In Progress Positive’:
Type_new[i]=‘High Potential’
elif data2[‘Status’][i]==‘Open’:
Type_new[i]=‘High Potential’
elif data2[‘Status’][i]==‘converted’:
Type_new[i]=‘High Potential’
else:
Type_new[i]= data2[“Status”][i]

data2.insert(6,“Status Clubbed”,Type_new)
data2.head(2)
```

```
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
in 
1 for i in range(len(data2.Status)):
----> 2 if data2[‘Status’][i]==‘Junk Lead’:
3 Type_new[i]=‘Low Potential’
4 elif data2[‘Status’][i]==‘Not Responding’:
5 Type_new[i]=‘Low Potential’

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in getitem(self, key)
866 key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
867 try:
–> 868 result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
869
870 if not is_scalar(result):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
4373 try:
4374 return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 4375 tz=getattr(series.dtype, ‘tz’, None))
4376 except KeyError as e1:
4377 if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your condition is just a mapping you can do this:

```
# Define a dictionary according to your condition to map your status
dictionary = {'Junk Lead': 'Low Potential', 'Not Responding': 'Low Potential',\
              'Just Enquiry': 'Low Potential', 'In Progress Negative': 'Low Potential',\
              'LOST': 'Low Potential', 'CONVERTED': 'High Potential', 'Potential': 'High Potential',\
              'Long Term': 'High Potential', 'In Progress Positive': 'High Potential',\
              'Open': 'High Potential', 'converted': 'High Potential'}

# Store the Status column with the keys replaced by their values from the dictionary
df["Status Clubbed"] = df.Status.replace(dictionary)
```

Documentation:

- [Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html): replace values from a Series based on to_replace argument.

Comment: I have used the replace logic and I have obtained the desired output, but, my requirement is that I want to insert a new column and then based on the condition specified, I need to pass on the string values.

Comment: @sujithnath - `data2.insert(6,“Status Clubbed”, df.Status.replace(dictionnary))` is what you want ? Sorry I didn't really get it, what is wrong if you have the expected output ?